# How to Set the name, email, and profile to respective field in Kotlin | Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication

Because of this two line my app is getting terminated

```
    sName = findViewById(R.id.user_name)
    sName.text = name
```

the complete code

```
//Write your code here
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    //display profile information such as profile_image, name, email account
    val user = mAuth.currentUser
    profileImage = user?.photoUrl.toString()
    name = user?.displayName.toString()
    email = user?.email.toString()

    Log.e("DisplayName", name)
    Log.e("Profile_url", profileImage)
    Log.e("Email", email)
```

What can be the solution for this

Comment: stacktrace please?

Comment: try `name = user?.displayName ?: "unknown"`

Comment: Are you sure that the user is authenticated?

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.